# Finding an open data layer which includes towns , villages and ciities in the UK

Tags: data, united-kingdom

I am looking for a data layer that i can import into Qgis to show towns, villages and cities. either of the three in an individual shp file would also be useful.

this is part of a project in which i am siting locations for windfarms and one critera for there posistioning is that they have to be over 2000m from a large dwelling

thus far i have found a buildings layer in Os vector district however this is not ideal.

Comment: Strategi® is a small scale data set https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/opendatadownload/products.html if you want large scale data go with the OS VectorMap® District (OS Names will be another option but not in shapefile)

Comment: i have looked at ones you have metioned however i do not understand how to find village city and town boundary shape files

Comment: are you after town/city boundaries or points (location)?

Comment: BoundaryLine is the for the areas https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-and-government/products/boundaryline.html but your going to get confused with Unitary Authorities, Metropolitan Districts, London Boroughs and Counties

Comment: Should probably buy mastermap for a windfarm development, since it will almost certainly go to planning appeal the cost is negligible